# Live migration of VMs in openstack

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, openstack, hyper-v

Is it possible to live migrate a virtual machine running on KVM host to Hyper-V based host in open-stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, live migration between different hypervisor types is simply impossible, unless you're running a layered solution and the actual VM is abstracted from the nested VM [1] you are migrating.

EDIT: [1] See what Ravello are doing

Answer (score 1):

I did a short google and would say: no.

main reason I found why it would not work:
* kvm usually uses raw or qcow2 images which are incompatible to hyper-v
* conversion of images to vhd would not be 'live'